# MySQL potential loss of space?

Tags: mysql

Maybe you have already figured I'm not really educated regarding MySQL and SQL in general due to the number of questions I have asked on this subject. What I want to ask may be really basic but I can't seem to find the answer in straight text, so please don't downvote just because the question is basic.

So I was wondering, since I have a table that is potentially going to reach a high amount of records and it has an auto increment key, I've set it to int(10) unsigned. But as I said supposedly it may go above that range and I wanted to ask if it were better to wait for a bunch of records to be inserted and then change the type or have it as bigint initially?

Comment: `int(10)` does **not** limit the valus to 10 digits! It is merely a hint for the client application on how many digits should be *displayed*. The values `int` and `int(10)` can store are absolutely identical.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name by first reading the question, I questioned myself about that. Maybe this is a confusion between `INT(10)` and `DECIMAL(10)` ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Just to be clear, although 10 digits are used for the display, the maximum value is 2,147,483,647 and not 9,999,999,999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have it be a `bigint` initially.  Modeling the data correctly greatly simplifies maintaining the database.

Also, the `id` is probably being used as a foreign key in other tables.  Changing such references requires changing multiple tables.

And, changing a data type on an empty table is easy and fast.  Changing a data type on an already populated table requires a lot of effort -- the data literally needs to be rewritten into the new type.

Comment: That seems logical, thank you for the reply but I was especially concerned about space. I read somewhere that certain data types preserve space even if it is not used. I was wondering if that was such case ?

Comment: As a complement, if you really have exceptional (!) storage requirements for an `auto_increment` column, you could double the number of (positive) ids by using the `SERIAL` type (which is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`) ;)

Comment: Well but also double and float seem to be slightly larger than bigint, why not use them, hypothetically?

Comment: @php_nub_qq . . . Floating point types are ill-advised for keys because "what you see" is not "what you get".  In other words, the low order bits of a floating point value are not captured when you look at it.  So, `4.5` could be `4.5000000000` or `4.50000000001` or `4.999999999` (for some number of `0`s and `9`s).  These would not match as a key, although they "look" the same.